# Decouple Json Deserialisation Keys > Properties mapping from Model. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, system.text.json

Using Net 6 and `System.Text.Json` I have:

```
public class Sensor {
  [JsonPropertyName("InstanceId")]
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("SensorName")]
  public String Name { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("IsValid")]
  public Boolean Valid { get; set; }
}
```

I need to parse Sensors from Json so I am using:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sensor>(json);
```

The use of `JsonPropertyName` is because `Sensor` properties names don't match Json keys.

I am getting Sensors data from different APIs and each one uses different keys.

I could use a Model per API: `SensorModelApi1`, `SensorModelApi2` with different `JsonPropertyName` values.

Then I would map each Sensor Model to Sensor class.

**Question**

Would be possible to decouple the Keys / Properties mapping from Sensor class?

Instead of using `JsonPropertyName` I would have other strategy for mapping for each API avoiding having a SensorModel for each API.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Since you are using System.Text.Json nothing makes any sense

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a good way to do this. If you really want a clean model, the only option I've found so far is to create API specific model objects with the necessary serialization attributes along with your model, then write a layer to transform those objects to your clean model objects and vice versa.

Comment: For each API, are all the properties in your deserialized object graph mapped in some consistent manner? Can you give some additional details about the mappings?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Newtonsoft json package instead, seems that [JsonProperty] will fix your issue.
Docs: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm

Comment: This is exactly what the op is already doing just with a different library. The question is about decoupling serialization attributes from the model